# Remove entries form CSV file based on a list in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a CSV file which has the following content:

```
Apple,Bat
Apple,Cat
Apple,Dry
Apple,East
Apple,Fun
Apple,Gravy
Apple,Hot
Bat,Cat
Bat,Dry
Bat,Fun
...
```

I also have a list as follows:

```
to_remove=[Fun,Gravy,...]
```

I would like an efficient way to delete all lines from the csv file which have any one of the words from the list to_remove.

I know one way to do it is to read each line of the csv file, loop through to_remove to see if any of the words are present in the line and save the line to another file if there was no match.

However, I have a lot of entries in both the csv file and the to_remove list (approx 21000 and 300 respectively). So I want a efficient way of doing it in Python.

I do not have access to clusters so map-reduce based options are not an option.

Comment: `grep -Ev '(Fun|Gravy)' filename`

Comment: You could try regular expressions or simply parallelise the code. There's only so much you can do. Huge operations will always be huge one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

```
toremove = ['Fun','Gravy']
with open('test.in','r') as fin, open('test.out','w') as fout:
    for i in filter(lambda x:not any(i for i in toremove if i in x), fin.readlines()):
        fout.write(i)

with open('test.out') as fout:
    print fout.read()
```

`test.in`:

```
Apple,Bat
Apple,Cat
Apple,Dry
Apple,East
Apple,Fun
Apple,Gravy
Apple,Hot
Bat,Cat
Bat,Dry
Bat,Fun
```

**[out:]**

```
Apple,Bat
Apple,Cat
Apple,Dry
Apple,East
Apple,Hot
Bat,Cat
Bat,Dry
```

Comment: `fin.readlines()` will read the entire file into memory. Not exactly what the OP wants.